# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable FLASK REST API endpoint test

Tags: unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to assert equal the data I stored in a SQLAlquemy db and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/jorgesisco/Documents/GitHub/FlaskRestAPI/tests/product_test.py", line 
34, in test_get
response_data = dict(response.json()[0])
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

---

```
import unittest
from app import app
import json

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        self.app = app.test_client()

def test_get(self):

    tester = app.test_client(self)
    response = tester.get('/product',
                           content_type='application/json')

    response_data = response.json()[0] # Here I get the error

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(response_data['category_id'], 1)
    self.assertEqual(response_data['description'], 'Nice Pants')
    self.assertEqual(response_data['product_image'], 'Image')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I did the call from a another python file and the syntax is correct in order to get the values from the database, maybe while testing the approach has to be different but I have not found the right way yet, If someone could tell me what am I missing it'd be nice.

Comment: Print the variable "response" and see what's inside

Answer (score 0):

By changing the syntax to response.json['id'], it worked.